# Is reading an encryption key from stdin a bad security practice?

Tags: security, encryption

I'm working on a new encryption utility, and was wondering if piping in an encryption key from another process is a bad security practice, or if the key should be sent between processes through shared memory or other similar system. In other words; is it likely that the key could "leak" to another, unauthorized process when the kernel is passing the buffered information between processes? In other words; could something bad happen here?

```
//Read encryption key
unsigned char enc_key[32];
read(STDIN_FILENO,enc_key,32);
//do some encryption/decryption with the key here
memset_s(enc_key,0,32);
```

Comment: My main concern is the possibility of the kernel buffer used to pipe information between the two processes being freed after the pipe is closed. The memory may then be given to another process without being zeroed, giving unauthorized access to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an encryption key via stdin is a bad security practice:

- first the streams are buffered:  an attacker could find your key easily, by analyzing the memory of your process.
- then, piping architecture makes it extremly easy to build [a man in the middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), passing through the key as if it came from the original process, but making a copy of it on the flow.

Prefer alternatives such as:

- Shared memory between two processes:  this leaves you in control of wiping out the memory that contained the key as soon as you don't need it anymore (as you tried to do with `memset_s()`). Consider the possibly of encrypting the shared memory with a session key.
- use of an SSL socket.

Keep in mind that your key should be stored itself encrypted in memory, and it should be decrypted only when needed and for as short pertiods as possible.  See [passwordsafe project](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/readmore.shtml) as example for  code storing keys with security in mind.

Comment: Thanks, shared memory with a session key seems to be the best way to go.